# Join2 tables and group by date

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to sum all win_ticket and divide it to the sum of all sold_ticket  from 2 tables to get the percentage and then group it by date.

This is not working at all.....

sold_ticket

[image]

customer_winner

[image]

```
$query = "SELECT 
      sold_ticket.date, sold_ticket.sold_ticket, 
              SUM(sold_ticket) AS sold_ticket, 
      customer_winner.date, customer_winner.win_ticket, 
              SUM(win_ticket) AS lottery_win

      FROM sold_ticket

      INNER JOIN customer_winner

      ON sold_ticket.date = customer_winner.date

      GROUP BY date 
      ";
```

Comment: Check this  `SUM((SUM(win_ticket)/SUM(sold_ticket))*100) as percentage`

Comment: It think the problem is that it won´t group by date because it is date in both tables?

Answer (score 0):

need to grouping sold_ticket.date or customer_winner.date or both of them.

try this

```
SELECT sold_ticket.date,
         SUM (sold_ticket) AS sold_ticket,
         SUM(customer_winner.win_ticket),
         SUM (win_ticket) AS lottery_win
    FROM sold_ticket
         INNER JOIN customer_winner ON sold_ticket.date= customer_winner.date
GROUP BY sold_ticket.date;
```